# Scale a vertex group in edit mode

Tags: mesh, workflow, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

For the sake of increasing work speed, I am looking for a way to setup quick scaling of solidify thickness in edit mode. The context is that I'm making mesh hair consisting of lots of different strands, and editing them manually. To make this as convenient as possible, I am using very low poly flat strands with a lot of subsurf, and then solidify to turn them into flattened cylinders.

I need to be able to make the strands different sizes and thicknesses. If the solidify were applied, this could be done with Shrink/Fatten. I can scale the strands based on normals to make them wider, but their fatness is defined by their weight in the solidify vertex group (and capped by the thickness set in the solidify modifier.)

To get the full functionality that I want, I need to be able to set a hotkey that lets me adjust the value of a vertex group on my selected object. Ideally, it would multiply based on mouse movement, like most modelling tools do. But I'd settle for being able to type a number to multiply it's current weight by.

So overall, what I would need is a way to multiply the value of the selected verts within the active vertex group, and have the Factor be based off mouse or keyboard input. Is there any way to set this up? Or an addon that could do it? And if not, would such an addon be possible?

Update: It looks like Gain from the Levels tool can multiply the weights. I can hotkey Levels, and it will repeat the last Gain setting whenever I use it, so that helps. But i can't have the Gain change based on a typed value or mouse movement without clicking around a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way that you can setup your screen to make it faster:
[image]

Try adding the vertex group to the Solidify modifier and set the max thickness.
Then you can either select some vertices and set the number directly or go into weight paint mode and paint in thickness.